# Combine multiple tabs into new one only for 4 columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would to combine all the tabs of my spreadsheet (only for the columns A,B,C,D) in a new tab that contains all these columns combined, and so:

New Tab created:
A,B,C,D (first tab) E,F,G,H (second tab) I,J,K,L (third tab)....

Comment: Can you please give us an example of what do you have and what do you want?

Comment: Please share a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
={
  array_constrain(Sheet1!A1:D, 100, 4), 
  array_constrain(Sheet2!A1:D, 100, 4), 
  array_constrain(Sheet3!A1:D, 100, 4), 
  array_constrain(Sheet4!A1:D, 100, 4) 
}
```